# Select distinct records from two different tables

Tags: sql, join, left-join, teradata

I have two databases:

```
Account Number:    Days Opened:
1                  3
2                  10
3                  30
4                  17

Account Number:    Company:   Transaction Date:
1                  ABC        1-1-1990
1                  ABC        2-1-1990
1                  ABC        3-1-1990
2                  DEF        10-2-1991
2                  DEF        11-2-1992
3                  GHI        20-3-1993
```

How do I get it to return the following (only looking at accounts opened less than twenty days):

```
Account Number:    Days Opened:   Company:
1                  3              ABC
2                  10             DEF
4                  17             ?
```

Anytime I try using a left join, it returns way more records than I want.

Comment: Those are two **tables**, not databases.

Answer (score 0):

Try below using inner join and distinct

```
select distinct t1.accountno,t1.daysopened,t2.Company from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
on t1.accountno=t2.accountno
and DaysOpened<20
```

Comment: Would that exclude all the records from the first database that don't have a match in the second table?

Comment: @klippy, yes it would definitely - you can execute it in your database

Comment: Is there anyway of including them as well? I'll edit my answer to include this

Comment: can you please provide your expected output

Comment: @klippy, I've modified my answer - you can check now just use left join and condition in on cluase

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is messed up.  The company should not be in the transactions table.  You should be looking it up -- presumably in the first table.

One method in Teradata uses `qualify`:

```
select t1.accountno, t1.daysopened, t2.company
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.acountno = t2.accountno
where t1.daysopened < 20
qualify row_number() over (partition by t2.accountno order by t2.transaction_date desc) = 1;
```

Comment: Its not a real database. Just an similar example I made up

Answer (score 0):

You could use a group by so you only return unique combinations:

```
sel a.account_number
, a.days_opened
, c.company
from accounts a
inner join companies c
on a.account_number = c.account_number
where a.days_opened < 20
group by 1,2,3
```

You could also use the left join if you want to have empty rows for account numbers that are not present in the company table. However, seeing your potential outcome I think you need an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Create table like yours.

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    ([AccountId] Int, [DaysOpened] Int)
;

INSERT INTO table1
    ([AccountId], [DaysOpened])
VALUES
    (1, 3),
    (2,10),
    (3,30),
    (4,17);

CREATE TABLE table2
    ([AccountId] Int, [Company] varchar(50),[TransactionDate] date)
;

INSERT INTO table2
    ([AccountId], [Company],[TransactionDate])
VALUES
    (1, 'ABC','1-1-1990'),
    (1, 'ABC','2-1-1990'),
    (1, 'ABC','3-2-1990'),
    (2, 'DEF','10-2-1990'),
    (3, 'GHI','20-3-1990');
```

And try this script.

```
select t1.AccountId,t1.DaysOpened,t2.Company from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 ON t1.AccountId=t2.AccountId
where DaysOpened < 20
Group by t1.AccountId,t1.DaysOpened,t2.Company
```

You can try with this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/35eeb/4)